# retrieve all datas from selected column and store

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Race");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo $row[0]; 
}
```

above is probably an awkward method but it'll print out all datas stored in first column, which is good but now, I want to  store each one of them into an array...

I tried

```
$array[$i]=$row[0];
```

and echoed it out, but it just prints"Array"...

I tried

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT raceid FROM Race");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[]=$row[0];
}
```

...which does the same as code written before, i guess, since it too just print "Array".

Please help! Thank you!!

Comment: You can't `echo` an array. Use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see what's in an array.

Comment: I recommend use ezSQL library.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use simple `echo $array;`? It's wrong. You can't output array this way.

Use this:

```
$array = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT raceid FROM Race");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[]=$row[0];
}

foreach($item in $array) {
    echo $item."<br>"; // and more format
}
```

If you want to watch array contents without any format use (e.g. for debugging) `print_r` or `var_dump`:

```
print_r($array);
var_dump($array);
```

**Advice**: better to use assoc array.

```
$array = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT raceid FROM Race");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[]=$row['raceid'];
}
```

**Advanced advice**: better to use PDO and object results.

1. You SQL code will be invulnerable to SQL injections
2. Code will be more modern and readable.